Large nonce leakage with single signature but not severe enough for being able to use Pollard kangaroo
There’s lot of papers on how to recover a private key from a nonce leakage in a ecdsa signature. But the less bits are known the more signatures are required.
Now, suppose I have a 150Bits nonce leakage on a secp256k1 signature, is it enough to recover the private key from a single signature? If yes how?

That will depend on the nature of the leakage. Not all 190-bit worth of leakage are equal. E.g. technically, the XOR of the 190 low-order bits of the nonce with the low-order 190 bits of the hash of the high-order 64 bits of the nonce yields a 190-bit leakage. But exploiting that leakage is hard. Are we free to assume what the leak is, e.g. the 190 high-order bits of the nonce?

@fgrieu In reality, I m just interested in a case where a leakage is severe enough to recover the private key from a single signature but still too large for Bruteforce/pollard Kangaroo.

This depends on precisely what information is leaked. Without further context, I assume that I have a single ECDSA signature $(r,s)$ associated with the usual base point $G$ and some public key point $A$. I also have 192-bits of information about $k$ where $kG=R$ where $R$ is a point with $x$-coordinate $r$.
Now, if this information is the low 190-bits of $k$ or the high 190-bits of $k$ (or more generally, if the unknown bits of $k$ form a contiguous group), I can recover the remaining 66-bits of $k$ using e.g. a feasible 33-bit Pollard kangaroo attack. This kanagaroo attack only needs knowledge of $G$, $R$ and the 190-bits of information about $k$; knowledge of $A$ or its associated private key is not needed.
Given $k$ it is then easy to recover the private key $a$ from the ECDSA equation $a=(sk-h(m))/r\pmod\ell$. Given this it is easy to compute the putative public key $A=aG$ and confirm that the signature corresponds to this key.

In reality, I m just interested in a case where a leakage is severe enough to recover the private key from a single signature but still too large for Bruteforce/pollard Kangaroo and thus requires data from the signature (like pubkey or what was signed).

And how you can use Pollard Kangaroo since you don t know the private key in order to check if the generated signature match?

@user2284570: in such attacks the standard assumption is that both the public key and the message matching the signature are available to the attacker. Please clarify what's available by editing the question (I initially misread your comment as making it like some of the public key or message might not be available). Changing other things (like 190 to 150) is more disputable.

@fgrieu that s the case but I don t see how it can help.
